# how to persist data in memory

Tags: redis, memcached, in-memory

I know a lot of libraries or applications that can persist data in memory, such as memcached, redis, or tachyon. But how do they do this?

As a solution I can imaging, maybe we can construct a object, or an array, or a list, or a map table to store the data, but this seems not a good solution. This is difficult to manage, or can easily lead to OutOfMemory or something else?

Is there a basic difference between all these systems?

Comment: memcached does not persist its data. Redis does it - read http://redis.io/topics/persistence . Tachyon will probably persist as well with a checkpoint mechanism, but it is on-going work.

Comment: yes, what I want to know is that how to persist data in memory, is there any useful material about the in-memory tech?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the the [architecture](http://www.enjoythearchitecture.com/redis-architecture) of Redis to find out at least how Redis saves data in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Tachyon, which provides implementation for In-memory Distributed Filesystem which can scale across multiple machines.

http://tachyon-project.org/

this approach is better than single machine solution.